# Group by dataframe on values from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df1 that I want to group with folowing columns

```
retailer                        object
store_id                         int64
visit_date              datetime64[ns]
categories_euclidean           float64
probes_euclidean               float64
```

I want to group it by following df2

```
          pk start_date   end_date
name                              
Cycle 01   1 2016-02-24 2016-03-13
Cycle 02   2 2016-03-14 2016-03-27
Cycle 03   3 2016-03-28 2016-04-10
Cycle 04   4 2016-04-11 2016-04-24
Cycle 05   5 2016-04-25 2016-05-08
Cycle 06   6 2016-05-09 2016-05-22
```

The filtering condition is: `df2.start_date <= df1.visit_date <= df2.end_date`,
and the groups names to be df2.names

Any idea how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def filt(x):
    cond1 = df2.start_date <= x
    cond2 = df2.end_date >= x
    return df2[cond1 & cond2].index[0]

df1['name'] = df1.visit_date.apply(filt)

df1.groupby('name')
```

I couldn't play around with this.  But it might work.